# How do I get this region?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image: q]

I tried to get the region by using spherical coordinates but I'm getting 2 intervals for $\rho$.
Also I don't see why $b \leq c/a$ is relevant

Comment: Hint one is the equation for a cylinder the other a circle. how do they relate?

Answer (score 1):

The inequality
$$a(x^2+y^2)+z^2\leq c^2,\quad \text{ or }\quad \frac{x^2}{(c/a)^2}+\frac{y^2}{(c/a)^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}\leq 1$$
is satisfied by the points inside the [ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid) centered at the origin with semi-axis, $c/a$, $c/a$ and $c$.

The other inequality
$$x^2+y^2\leq b^2$$
is satisfied by the points inside the infinite [cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder) with axis the $z$-axis and with radius $b$.

The condition $b\leq c/a$ means that the "base" of the cylinder in  the $xy$-plane is inside the "equatorial" section of the ellipsoid. Hence their intersection is just a part of the ellipsoid.
If $b>c/a$ then the infinite-cylinder contains the whole ellipsoid.

Are you able to evaluate the volume of the intersection ellipsoid-cylinder now?